# How to put my text after the content products?

Tags: text-align

So i have a ecommerce, and i'm writing a text to optimize the SEO, but I need the text must be align AFTER the products content and not before. It is a Simples CSS script?

This is the page: https://letsfitsp.com.br/comprar-marmitas-congeladas-sp

and this is the HTML text:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><meta charset="utf-8" /></p>

<h1 dir="ltr"><b id="docs-internal-guid-f48b1604-7fff-3fb9-2913-5d5967828808">As Marmitas Congeladas SP Let&rsquo;s Fit: Alto Padr&atilde;o de Qualidade</b></h1>

<p dir="ltr"><b id="docs-internal-guid-f48b1604-7fff-3fb9-2913-5d5967828808">Sabemos, o que voc&ecirc; busca &eacute; ter op&ccedil;&otilde;es e varia&ccedil;&otilde;es de marmitas congeladas SP, n&atilde;o &eacute;? Aqui na Let&rsquo;s Fit te entregamos sabor, com qualidade elevada e muitas escolhas diversificadas de comida congelada em S&atilde;o Paulo.</b></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h2 dir="ltr"><b id="docs-internal-guid-f48b1604-7fff-3fb9-2913-5d5967828808">Alimentos Fitness e melhores marmitas congeladas SP e Grande S&atilde;o Paulo | S&oacute; na Let&rsquo;s Fit</b></h2>

<p dir="ltr"><b id="docs-internal-guid-f48b1604-7fff-3fb9-2913-5d5967828808">Todos n&oacute;s temos ci&ecirc;ncia da import&acirc;ncia da boa nutri&ccedil;&atilde;o e como ela se faz importante para nosso condicionamento f&iacute;sico e sa&uacute;de como um todo. Uma rotina com equil&iacute;brio nos fortalece para enfrentar nossa cansativa e pesada rotina.</b></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS is a factor of SEO rank, but more in terms of legibility. For example a small font or hidden content would not positively impact SEO score. HTML which uses semantic elements such as `<main>` is more consumable to a spider crawl (regardless of order). Developers use tools such as Lighthouse to find reports. Often you may find it best to craft a canonical document to provide for page rank, which could be done with a plugin such as Yoast.